# convert a column to date format in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and struggling with how to create a vector with a date format. I want the following vector to recognise as a year in my data frame.

year <- c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021)

I would highly appreciate it if someone can help me with the above.

Comment: `Date` class includes day and month.  What would be your expected day, month given only the 'year'

Comment: I need only the year because in the other column I will put sales for the whole year. In the case it is necessary to put the date, it is ok to put financial year end date Ex:- 30/06/2013

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the first of the year as a Date class vector here are several ways.  The first creates POSIXct datetimes and then converts that to Date class.  The second creates character string representations of the date and then converts that to Date class.  The third creates a yearmon class sequence and then converts that to Date class.

```
year <- 2012:2021

# 1. this uses no packages
as.Date(ISOdate(year, 1, 1))
##  [1] "2012-01-01" "2013-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2016-01-01"
##  [6] "2017-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01"

# 2. this also uses no packages. It gives the same result.
as.Date(paste0(year, "-1-1"))

# 3. this gives same result
library(zoo)
as.Date(as.yearmon(year))
```

To get the last day of the year use these respectively.  The last one first calculates the first date of the next year and then subtracts one day to get the last day of the current year.

```
as.Date(ISOdate(year, 12, 31))

as.Date(paste0(year, "-12-31"))

library(zoo)
as.Date(as.yearmon(year + 1)) - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can save the YEAR portion as a DATE object. But, you can certainly convert using data wrangling techniques and the handy `lubridate` package as you can see from the below:

```
library(lubridate)

new_year <- mdy(paste0(1,"-",1,"-",year))

new_year
 [1] "2012-01-01" "2013-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01"

> class(new_year)
[1] "Date"
```

The year() function allows you to convert a DATE object to year, but this would be converted to a "numeric" type, hence think most likely you cannot get a DATE object with only YEAR.

Comment: It really worked. Thanks for helping me. If you don't mind can you bit explain what the following part of the function do, .....(paste0(1,"-",1,"-",

Comment: paste0 is a function that combines different characters into a new string. So excluding the comma we are saying create a new vector that combines "1" and "-" and "1" and "-" the elements from your original vector (i.e. the 4 digit numbers corresponding to year). So it would be converted into "1-1-2012" but would still be as a character string. Secondly mdy() is a lubridate function that converts a character strings to DATE format when you have the string in an orderly format MonthDateYear format, hence it then becomes a DATE object. You can deal with any format using the lubridate library.